# go redis HMSet fail

Tags: go, redis

When I use redis hmset in Go I get the following problem, why is it?
`ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command`
Resulting in values not being stored in redis ?
I'm referring to the redis book, why is this a problem ?

```golang
func (r *ArticleRepo) PostArticle(user, title, link string) string {
    articleId := strconv.Itoa(int(r.Conn.Incr("article:").Val()))

    voted := "voted:" + articleId
    r.Conn.SAdd(voted, user)
    r.Conn.Expire(voted, common.OneWeekInSeconds*time.Second)

    now := time.Now().Unix()
    article := "article:" + articleId
    _, err := r.Conn.HMSet(article, map[string]interface{}{
        "title":  title,
        "link":   link,
        "poster": user,
        "time":   now,
        "votes":  1,
    }).Result()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    r.Conn.ZAdd("score:", &redis.Z{Score: float64(now + common.VoteScore), Member: article})
    r.Conn.ZAdd("time:", &redis.Z{Score: float64(now), Member: article})
    return articleId
}
```

Comment: I'd make sure that your articleId is filled with some value for sure otherwise the article may end in ":".

Secondly, you're running **HMSET**, but why are you getting wrong of number of arguments for **HSET**? Make sure to look at the correct error.

Comment: Use hset instead of HMSET, HMSet is a deprecated version of HSet left for compatibility with Redis 3.

Comment: Thank you@ManjeetThakur Problem solved with hset

Comment: Hi @zqm it would be nice, if you could shortly describe solution in an answer and mark it as accepted answer. That way, future people will have it easier to find a solution to similar problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hset instead of hmset with something like this in Go:

```
 _, err := r.Conn.Do("hset", article, map[string]interface{}{
    "title":  title,
    "link":   link,
    "poster": user,
    "time":   now,
    "votes":  1,
}).Result()
```